# How to connect atmega 32 to webserver wirelessly?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, atmega16

I am doing a project where in i am using Atmega 32. Atmega32 will be receiving the content from the sensors using RF communication. Now i want to store this data directly on my webserver. I have searched on the net. I got a particular IC that TI manufactures.(CC3000). Due to cost constraints, i need an alternative solution:
1)Can someone help me with an alternative IC that i can interface with Atmega
2)Worst case-Should i change my microcontroller that has some inbuilt wireless communication set up..

Additional information as to how do i load the information on the webserver will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad and would benefit being split into smaller questions. I'd ask part 1 over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ the webserver part would be a question on it's own after you figure out how to connect to it.

Comment: You can try out http://www.rhydolabz.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1452, WiFly module. Microcontroller can communicate to this module through serial port and is easy to use. I have tested this for home automation and works good.